# Testing glfwSetErrorCallback(...)

Tags: glfw

I'm developing a 2D-graphics application using th LWJGL library, which uses GLFW.

Somewhere in my code I want to implement custom error handling using

```
glfwSetErrorCallback(...)
```

Now I want to trigger some kind of GLFW error to see if my approach works.

Are there any possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @httpdigest, here is a way to to trigger a GLFW error:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 99); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 99); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 
glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Test", NULL, NULL);
```

Setting only `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR` or only `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` to an invalid value is sufficient.